# How to loop through scale keyframes of text object in blender

Tags: python, animation, blender

I'm trying to extract some data from Blender. I have a text a layer and couple of other objects in the scene and they change in scale. scale value of 0 then a linear increase in size from 0-0.35 and then pause. I want to be able to extract the time stamps of those keyframes. I want to loop through the list of objects with specific name and extract the data above

I'm a newbie at this and still getting my head around working with blender in python so any and all help is appreciated.

The eventual process is to export this data as a JSON data to be used in another software.

I was thinking something like

```
for frame in range(frames):
    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if "Text in Camera" in ob.name:
            #Pseudo Code
            startPoint=ob.scale.startPoint
            endPoint=ob.scale.endPoint
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
```

Thanks!

Tried iterating through the frames and getting the scale data, but blender crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution: loop through all the objects (replace "Cube" with "Text in camera" in your example) and search any actions on the object where the scale is altered, and store the keyframes of those actions in a list, which you can then output as JSON data.

```
import bpy    
        
list_of_keyframes = []
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.name.startswith("Cube"):
        for fc in o.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            if fc.data_path.endswith('scale'):
                for key in fc.keyframe_points :
                    kfr = [o.name, key.co[0], key.co[1]]
                    if kfr not in list_of_keyframes:
                        list_of_keyframes.append(kfr)

print(list_of_keyframes)
```

Note that Blender stores scaling on different axes as different actions, so if you have one object that is scaled from 0 to 0.35 on the X, Y and Z-axis (I assumed that was the case), you get 3 actions. The loop above only stores a combination of keyframe and scale if it hasn't appeared in the list yet, to avoid doubles.

Also there is a special Stackexchange for Blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/